# How to apply actionscript 3 radial effect in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, effects

In actionscript 3 I want to apply a special effect which will render my flat 2d layout into a radial form.

Is there a way to achieve such an effect with existing features or should that be developed first by using alchemy?

External Example:
[alt text http://d2syub29v5lge2.cloudfront.net/web/playfishcom/img/crazy_planets/cp_screenshot2_640.jpg](http://d2syub29v5lge2.cloudfront.net/web/playfishcom/img/crazy_planets/cp_screenshot2_640.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pixel bender to create a custom filter for this, or you could try to use displacements maps. Either method could end up looking pixel-y or distorted and not necessarily what you want. The above example seems like it's being played on a circular game map rather than being a rendering effect.

Comment: At this time i am looking for pixel-y or distorted result. Could you provide an example for displacements maps or custom filter?

Comment: I found the example:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/12/03/understanding-flash-displacement-map-filter/